# One div per row when the window is narrow, more divs per row when it's wider

Tags: css

I've got multiple independent boxes on my page all using {float:left}.  There's nothing else around for them to interfere with.

When the window is narrow, I'd like the boxes to be {width:100%}.  When the window is wide enough for two boxes to fit side by side, I'd like the boxes to be {width:50%}.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Define your measurements for 'narrow'

Comment: Off the cuff, let's say the boxes should be at least 100px if they're going to be side by side.  If there isn't at least 200px wide of space for them, then there should only be one box on a row, taking up 100% of the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only substantive answers so far have been using media queries, which I can't figure out how to get working.  Here's the solution I've found:

```
<div class="columns">
   <div class="box">
      <p>A bunch of stuff in the box.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then attach to that some CSS:

```
div.columns {
   column-width: 300px;
}
div.box {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

This isn't perfect, but it keeps the content at 100% width, no matter how many boxes fit side by side at any given screen size, and it lets me control how narrow a box is allowed to get (using div.columns' column-width).

Answer (score 2):

Media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width:600px){
     div{width:50%; float:left;}
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DYxxF/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way of achieving this is using media queries.

For inspiration (or simply to use), you can check out http://cssgrid.net

The grid system adjusts to the current size of the browser window, and works really well in my opinion. If you want something customized, their CSS is a pretty good example.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but it sounds like you're asking about [Responsive Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)